# Rails 4 - Display Nested Records Table, Vertically Formatted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to display all the child records of an object on a view in this table format:

```
obj 1 | obj 2 | obj 3 | obj 4
-----------------------------
attr 1| attr 1| attr 1| attr 1
-----------------------------
attr 2| attr 2| attr 2| attr 2
-----------------------------
attr 3| attr 3| attr 3| attr 3
-----------------------------
attr 4| attr 4| attr 4| attr 4
```

There will always be 4 columns, even if there are less than 4 objects (they would just remain empty). What I'm unsure about is how to loop through the attributes and then in turn display the attribute for each object so that the table follows the above format.

I have tried:

```
<% @parent.children.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value| %>
  <% @parent.children.each do |itm| %>
    <% itm.attr_value %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

With the code above, I get an error of `undefined method 'attributes'`.

Comment: where you found `child` method ? Did you define it, if so what does it return?

Comment: @ArupRakshit `child` isn't a method. It is just what I'm using to reference the nested records. `parent` has a has_many relationship with `child`, `child` belongs_to `parent`

Comment: ok.. then you should write as `children`..not `child`

Comment: Please show us your models.

Comment: `@parent.child` gives you an array, so you got error. You need to use `@parent.child.first.attributes.each...`

Comment: @ArupRakshit That makes sense, but then how do I access the item's individual attribute? At `<% itm.attr_value %>` I get an error as I figured I might. I'm not sure how to use the attribute name in a variable to get the value from `itm`.

Comment: `itm.send(attr_value)` will work.. But it would be good to your models.. to make the code more clean..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you're looking for?

```
<% @parent.children.each do |itm| %>
  <%= itm.name %>
<% end %>

<% attributes = @parent.children.first.attributes %>

<% attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value| %>
  <% @parent.children.each |itm| %>
    <%= itm.send(attr_name) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: No, that produces a table with objects displayed in rows. I want them displayed in columns as described in the question.

Comment: @honestinjun Edited the answer, read the question wrong. I haven't used erb in a while so maybe there could be a small syntax error somewhere.